# Engagement Plans in Sitecore 10

Tags: upgrade, marketing-automation, marketing-control-panel

We are looking to upgrade to `Sitecore 10 from Sitecore 8.1`, the current site using `Marketing Engagement Plan(s)`.

Are engagement plans used in Sitecore 10? If not what are they replaced with and is there a current upgrade path or a rebuild?

Answer (score 2):

Engagement plans are replaced by Marketing Automation plans from Sitecore 9.

I don't think there is an upgrade path offered by Sitecore. You can refer this answer from Pete - https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/9591/4515

So, you may have to rebuild them manually.

**References:**

https://www.sitecore.com/knowledge-center/blog/2018/sitecore-9-marketing-automation